# Hyper-V stuck restoring VM

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, hyper-v

I have a hyper-v server that runs 5 virtual machines. I believe the physical box rebooted last night which is usually not a problem but this morning one of the virual machines is stuck at "restoring 0%". I have rebooted the physical machine and same thing, 4 virtual machines come up fine the 5th gets stuck at "restoring 0%". I right-clicked the VM in hyper-v manager and selected "Cancel restore" and nothing happens. I was able to copy the VHD to another hyper-v box and light it up there so I know the VHD is good.

Any ideas on what to look at next? If I can I would like to just dump the saved state and move on, or if there is a better way to handle it I'm all ears.

TIA!!

Comment: I seem to remember this being a known problem with Server 2008 (non-R2) Hyper-V. Have you installed SP2 and all applicable updates? You should be able to kill the host process and delete the saved data, then restart the VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the VHD that you copied of that VM, and save it. Delete the VM in the Hyper-V manager, move the backed up copy to its original location. Create a new VM, and when it asks to create a hard drive, pick that VHD. This should get you where you want to be.

Comment: This strategy may have some negative side effects, such as changing the machine ID and MAC address, and perhaps breaking backup jobs that are looking for the original VM.

Answer (score 2):

I got mine up by:

1. killing the “HyperV worker process” in task manager.
2. Deleting the state (right click on vm and select delete state)
3. Starting the vm